# Unusually slow query across a join table

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that is strangely slow in Postgres 13 for a database containing only small amounts of data. I have even seen the problem in my test suite where I fabricate some fake data.

```sql
SELECT sales.* FROM sales 
INNER JOIN members ON members.id = sales.member_id
INNER JOIN members_teams ON members_teams.member_id = members.id 
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.id = members_teams.team_id 
WHERE teams.id IN (1, 2)
```

In my test suite I have the following counts of data in the different tables:

```
| Table         | Count          |
| --------      | -------------- |
| members       | 501            |
| teams         | 3              |
| members_teams | 501            |
| sales         | 502            |
```

Here is an example of when it is slow:

```sql
Nested Loop  (cost=0.75..25.83 rows=1 width=631) (actual time=38226.620..38226.622 rows=0 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (members_teams.team_id = teams.id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.75..24.82 rows=1 width=635) (actual time=0.082..38220.385 rows=502 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (members.id = members_teams.member_id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 251000
        ->  Index Scan using index_members_teams_on_team_id on members_teams  (cost=0.25..8.26 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.031..0.544 rows=501 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.50..16.54 rows=1 width=635) (actual time=0.014..76.217 rows=502 loops=501)
              Join Filter: (sales.member_id = members.id)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 125250
              ->  Index Scan using index_sales_on_member_id on sales  (cost=0.25..8.26 rows=1 width=631) (actual time=0.005..0.262 rows=502 loops=501)
              ->  Index Only Scan using members_pkey on members  (cost=0.25..8.26 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.124 rows=251 loops=251502)
                    Heap Fetches: 63001752
  ->  Seq Scan on teams  (cost=0.00..1.00 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=502)
        Filter: (id = ANY ('{1,2}'::integer[]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3
Planning Time: 0.690 ms
Execution Time: 38226.701 ms
```

Here is an example of when it is a more normal speed:

```sql
Nested Loop  (cost=0.75..24.82 rows=1 width=631) (actual time=224.746..224.747 rows=0 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (members.id = members_teams.member_id)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.50..16.54 rows=1 width=635) (actual time=0.047..80.953 rows=502 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (sales.member_id = members.id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 125250
        ->  Index Scan using index_sales_on_member_id on sales  (cost=0.25..8.26 rows=1 width=631) (actual time=0.015..0.367 rows=502 loops=1)
        ->  Index Only Scan using members_pkey on members  (cost=0.25..8.26 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.131 rows=251 loops=502)
              Heap Fetches: 125752
  ->  Index Only Scan using index_members_teams_on_member_id_and_team_id on members_teams  (cost=0.25..8.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.286..0.286 rows=0 loops=502)
        Filter: (team_id = ANY (‘{1,2}’::integer[]))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 501
        Heap Fetches: 251502
Planning Time: 0.481 ms
Execution Time: 224.798 ms
```

**Summary**

A key difference seems to be which index it uses for the join table `members_teams`. Do you have any suggestions for how I can make this consistently performant? I thought about removing the join to `teams` and filtering on the `team_id` on the join table, but I'm worried that in the future we may need to use this query with additional constraints from the `teams` table.

Answer (score 1):

Your estimates seem completely off. Do you have autovacuum disabled, or is your statistics collector malfunctioning? You should get better plans by explicitly collecting statistics:

```
ANALYZE sales;
ANALYZE members;
ANALYZE members_teams;
```